# Bit Fields vs Integer

Tags: variables, memory, integer, bit-fields

I'm writing an API that gets information about the CPU (using CPUID). What I'm wondering is should I store the values from the bit field returned by calling CPUID in separate integer values, or should I just store the entire bit field in a value and write functions to get the different values on-the-fly?

What is preferable in this case? Memory usage or speed? If it's memory usage, I'll just store the entire bit field in a single variable. If it's speed, I'll store each value in a separate variable.

Comment: You're asking **us** about what **your** priorities are?

Comment: Hey, I'm just asking what people's opinions are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only going to query a CPU once. With modern computers having both huge amounts of memory and processing power, it would make no difference either way.

Just do what would make more sense for the next person who reads it.

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.
>
> — *The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not matter here, b/c you will not call your CPU-id code 10000 times per second.. will you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define different interface (method) for different value. this is more clear and easy to use. a clear, accuracy & easy to use of interface should be the first thing to consider, then performance (memory usage & speed).